# mobile menu failing to trigger real-time

Tags: javascript, css, menu

Really strange one here, so I have recreated my problem in a fiddle but it works in there. I have copied my css, JS and html entirely.

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/7JWgt/1/)

The menu works perfectly in the fiddle, yet in real time - the menu works partially, you can click right next to the menu icon top open it up but its  struggle to find the trigger to send it back up. wondering if anyone can spot the error as I am stuck!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
    });
});

<div id="menumobile">
    <div id="nav-mobile">
        <br /><br />
            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.drdenimjeans.com/skin/frontend/drdenim/default/img/menu-icon.png" alt="Menu" class="menuimage"/></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php" class="mainmenu">ENGAGE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.php" class="mainmenu">FEATURES</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.php" class="mainmenu">DESIGN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php" class="mainmenu">PACKAGES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.php" class="mainmenu">CONTACT</a></li>                         
                </ul>
        <br /><br />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real error, but I would make the link be `display:inline-block` so that it will expand to contain the image.

```
#nav-mobile > a {display:inline-block;}
```

---

**update**

just noticed, shouldn't the `$('#nav-mobile').click` be `$('#nav-mobile > a').click` ? (*targeting the `a` and not the whole `ul`*)

Comment: Am I to be replacing this with anything or add it to the css?

Comment: just add it to the css. (*if you can put a link to the actual version with the problem we might see if something else is interfering with the link..*)

Comment: Its currently local but let me get it on a subdomain somehwere.

Comment: You Sir are a genious it was $('#nav-mobile a').click